# Python formatting decimals not to be a list in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, format, decimal

So I ran into this problem when trying to format numbers to have two decimal places. While I know you can use  this code `'[%.2f'%i for i in price_data]`

```
price1 = 1
price2 = 2
price3= 200
price4 =500
price5 =600

price_data = [price1, price2, price3, price4, price5]

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

gem = 'gold'

row1 = [gem, price1, price2, price3, price4, price5 ]
print(row1)
```

```
output = ['gold', 1, 2, 200, 500, 600]
```

```
row2 =[gem, ['%.2f'%i for i in price_data]]
print(row2)
```

```
output = ['gold', ['1.00', '2.00', '200.00', '500.00', '600.00']]
```

I want to get the same answer but not have the output be a list in a list. Is there any around this last output so that I get it as the following item returned?

```
output = ['gold', '1.00', '2.00', '200.00', '500.00', '600.00']
```

Comment: Maybe `row2 =[gem, *['%.2f'%i for i in price_data]]`

Comment: If you were helped by any of the answers, can you please mark one as accepted?

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using an f-string instead of the older `%` interpolation:

```py
output = [gem, *(f'{i:.2f}' for i in price_data)]
```

The other change I've made is to remove the comprehension and use a generator instead. This means that the price data `list` isn't created in memory first and then unpacked. This is the fastest, most memory efficient of the suggestions so far.

EDIT: I've deleted my other suggestions since everybody else answered at roughly the same time with those same answers.

Answer (score 0):

You may either

- flatten the inner list into the outer one

  ```
  row2 = [gem, *['%.2f' % i for i in price_data]]
  ```
- or concatenate the lists

  ```
  row2 = [gem] + ['%.2f' % i for i in price_data]
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't concatenate it because that gem is actually a part of a for loop, but the top one does so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
gem = 'Gold'
gem_l = [gem]

for i in my_list:
  gem_l.append(i)

print(gem_l)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work because you need the decimal format